# Auto-scaling is taking more time to bring up new pod and giving connection error in google container engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I have used following command  for autoscaling.

```
kubectl autoscale deployment catch-node --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=10
```

The status of autoscaling in my case on load test is as like below .

27th minute

```
NAME         REFERENCE                     TARGET    CURRENT   MINPODS   MAXPODS   AGE
catch-node   Deployment/catch-node/scale   50%       20%      1         10        27m

NAME         DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
catch-node   1         1         1            1           27m
```

29th minute

```
NAME         REFERENCE                     TARGET    CURRENT   MINPODS   MAXPODS   AGE
catch-node   Deployment/catch-node/scale   50%       35%      1         10        29m

NAME         DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
catch-node   1         1         1            1           29m
```

31st minute

```
NAME         REFERENCE                     TARGET    CURRENT   MINPODS   MAXPODS   AGE
catch-node   Deployment/catch-node/scale   50%       55%      1         10        31m

NAME         DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
catch-node   1         1         1            1           31m
```

34th minute

```
NAME         REFERENCE                     TARGET    CURRENT   MINPODS   MAXPODS   AGE
catch-node   Deployment/catch-node/scale   50%       190%      1         10        34m

NAME         DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
catch-node   4         4         4            4           34m
```

Here i am  getting connection refusing error in the time between transition of 1 pod to 4pods on autoscaling. Please let me know how much time it will take to bring up new pods once it exceed the CPU % limit given during autoscale .Also please let me know is there any method to reduce this time .once all new pods comes up, the issue is not there . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in this [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/docs/design/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.md#autoscaling-algorithm), there are two factors affect the reaction time of the autoscaler:

1. `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period`, which defines how often the autoscaler checks the status of the controlled resources. The default value is 30s. It can be changed via the flag of the controller-manager.
2. `upscaleForbiddenWindow`, which defines how often the autoscaler can scale up the resource. The default value is 3 mins. Currently it's not adjustable.

According to the log you pasted, if the load is stable, the autoscaler should reacted in 30s after CPU usage reaches 55%, is that the case?